# In Laravel Filament's form how precharge a textfield?

Tags: sum, laravel-8, laravel-filament

In a Form i need to obtain the max ('invoice_number') and add 1 before to show in TextForm::invoice_number -> disabled()
Can anyone help me??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Declare $invoiceNumber as public string and asign it in the mount method

```
public string $invoiceNumber = 1;

public function mount(): void
 {

    $this->form->fill([
        'invoice_number' => $this->invoiceNumber,
    ]);
}
```

No, in the getFormSchema method the field

```
  ...::make('invoice_number')
```

will be prefilled.